# Python - Save a map - Using ArcGIS - 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, save, arcgis

```
webmap_properties = {'title':'My first map of badminton courts in HK',
                    'snippet': 'Jupyter notebook saved as a webmap',
                    'tags':['automation', 'python','ArcGIS Notebooks']}
my_first_map.save(webmap_properties)
```

it says the 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable, what I should do?

Answer (score 0):

How are you declaring **my_first_map**?

This may work

```
import arcgis
from arcgis.gis import GIS
from arcgis.mapping import WebMap

my_first_map = WebMap()

webmap_properties = {'title':'My first map of badminton courts in HK',
                    'snippet': 'Jupyter notebook saved as a webmap',
                    'tags':['automation', 'python','ArcGIS Notebooks']}

my_first_map.save(item_properties=webmap_properties)
```

Anyway, here are some examples that might help:
https://developers.arcgis.com/python/sample-notebooks/publishing-web-maps-and-web-scenes/